# How to process the json to normal class object?

Tags: java, android, json, jsonobjectrequest

I'm doing post request with JsonObjectRequest with parameters(from model class). It looks like,

```
        SignUpRequest registrationRequest = new SignUpRequest();
        registrationRequest.setFirstName("fdffdfd");
        registrationRequest.setLastName("bbbbbb");
        registrationRequest.setEmail("Testing@kjkjgmail.com");
        registrationRequest.setDateOfBirth("1991-5-21");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(registrationRequest);

        JSONObject parameters = null;
        try {
            parameters = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, uri, parameters,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.v("MainActivity", "In response :");
                        updateDisplayRegistration(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "In failure :");
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(postRequest);
```

SignUpRequest class i have setters and getter methods. Like way for response also i have RegistrationInfo class which is having setters and getters of response object.

Now the problem is how can i handle response to get it as a RegistrationInfo class object.

```
protected void updateDisplayRegistration(JSONObject json){

        RegistrationInfo regInfo  = new RegistrationInfo(json.toString());

        Log.v("MainActivity","registered email is ::::: ---- ::: " + regInfo.getEmail());
}
```

But it is returning null. Even i tried with directly on json object it is also not returning any values.

Like,   `json.getString("email");`

How could i process response?

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing library Gson(to be a bit specific com.google.Gson) which can be used to convert JsonObject to java beans. You can do it as

`RegistrationInfo regInfo  = new GSON(json.toString(),RegistrationInfo.class);`

The Gson library uses reflection methods to convert a JSON string to Java bean internally.

Comment: are you sure it is GSON.. or it is Gson?

Because for GSON i can't find any library and more ever it gives an error.